# Is there any difference/advantage of using var before a variable name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am learning javascript . And I noted that the instructor was making variables in two ways .
first was (for example):

```
var name ="Any string here";
```

and second method was simply writing the variable name without writing var first :

```
name="Any string here";
```

And the result was same . 
So , is there any difference between these two ?. Which one is better to use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, it is a bad practice to not write `var` before variable
  declaration.
- Second problem is a global declaration of variable without `var`.
- Third, in
  `strict mode` using variable without declaration will cause Exception

Comment: would you please explain your third point , with an example ?

Comment: In JS you can write your code in `strict mode`. It helps you to avoid many strange things and strange behavior of your code. To enable strict mode, you just need to write `"use strict";` in the first line of your JS file (or function, if you want to enable strict mode only in one function). You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: So, when you have strict mode enabled in your code, and you trying to use variable without declaration, it will cause error. For example:
    `"use strict";
    a = 5; // Exception`

Comment: Glad to help ^__^ Just always use `var` and you will be ok ;D Also, in ES6 (ES2015, it's a new standard of JavaScript), instead of `var` you will be able to use `const` and `let`, but do not think about it now. Find some good book about JS, complete it first, and after that read about ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving out `var` makes it a global variable, so if you have `name` multiple places in the code, they'll overwrite each other.

Comment: and if suppose a variable is defined inside a function without writing var before it , then it will be local variable . Am I right ?

Comment: No - if you don't use var when declaring it, it becomes a global variable no matter where you declare it.